# Uncountable Disjoint Union of $\mathbb{R}$ and Local Euclideanness

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, manifolds

I'm working on Lee: Introduction to Smooth Manifolds problem 1-2 which asks to prove that the uncountable disjoint union of copies of $\mathbb{R}$ is locally euclidean, and just wanted to verify/disprove a thought I had regarding the question.

I've thought about the construction for some time and have concluded that it's equivalent to $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with the disjoint topology $\times$ $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with the usual topology.

From that construction, would it be safe to assume that at each point, we could construct a local open neighborhood that is homeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$? My reasoning is that the disjoint topology implies that each disjoint point is an open set, and then an open neighborhood of a point $(i, r)$ would be akin to $(i, (r-\epsilon, r+\epsilon))$ (where $i$ belongs to the copy of $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with the disjoint topology and $r$ belongs to $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with the usual topology). This can then be mapped by a homeomorphism to an open neighborhood of $\mathbb{R}^n$ by way of bases (not 100% sure how to deal with $i$ in this case though, as it is a singleton).

Is the idea correct, or have I made an error somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> From that construction, would it be safe to assume that at each point, we could construct a local open neighborhood that is homeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

No.

Consider $X=\bigsqcup_{i\in I}X_i$ for some (uncountable or not) set $I$, where each $X_i\equiv\mathbb{R}$ is just a copy. Formally $X_i=\{i\}\times\mathbb{R}$ and $X=\bigcup_{i\in I}X_i$. The topology on disjoint union is defined as follows: $U\subseteq X$ is open if and only if $U\cap X_i$ is open in $X_i$ for every $i\in I$. Formally, the topology on $X_i$ is given by the product topology and thus $X_i$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ via $(i,r)\mapsto r$.

In particular each $X_i$ is open in $X$. Therefore we can construct a straight forward atlas: each point $x\in X$ belongs to exactly one $X_i$ and thus the homeomorphism we are looking for is the trivial $X_i\to\mathbb{R}$ homeomorphism:
$(i,r)\mapsto r$. This shows that $X$ is of dimension $1$, even though it can be arbitrarly big as a set.

Comment: It’s just the boring way to construct non-separable manifolds.